# How to get a listview to refresh with new data from a Kendo datasource

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik-appbuilder

How do I get my list view page to refresh when I load new data into my kendo.data.DataSource?

I'm working on a Hybrid Mobile app using Telerik AppBuilder.
I have a simple listview that is bound to a data source.
I use an ajax POST request to load some JSON,
then place it in the datasource.
I have two pages, home and list view.
The home has some anchors that lead to a single list view page,
but with different data id values to produce different lists.

The first time I the list view page it loads correctly.
After that, the list view does not refresh when I reload the datasource;
the contents of the first list always display no matter what data id value I send in.

Here is the source:

**JavaScript**

```
window.APP =
{
    blamListSource: null,

    home:
    {
      fetchBlam: function(event)
      {
        var argumentData = event.button.data();
        var requestBody =
        {
          "requestVersionId": "1",
          "blamId": argumentData.id.toString()
        };

        $.ajax(
          {
            url: getBlamURI,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json',

            success: function(requestData, textStatus, jqxhr)
            {
              APP.blamListSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
                {
                  data: requestData.userList,
                });

              APP.blamListSource.read();

              app.navigate("views/blamlist.html");
            },

            error: function(jqxhr, textStatus, error)
            {
              alert("Error");
            },
          });
      }
    }
};
```

**home.html**

```
<div data-role="view" data-title="Home" data-layout="main"
     data-model="APP.models.home" data-zoom="true">
  <div id="form-blam" data-role="content">
    <a id="commercial" data-role="button"
       data-bind="click: fetchBlam" data-id="27">Something</a>
    <a id="personal" data-role="button"
       data-bind="click: fetchBlam" data-id="39">Something Else</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**views/blamlist.html**

```
<div data-role="view" data-title="Blam List" data-layout="main"
     data-model="APP" data-zoom="true">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <a class="nav-button" data-align="left" data-role="backbutton">Back</a>
  </div>
  <ul id="blam-listview" data-style="inset" data-role="listview"
      data-template="blamListTemplate" data-bind="source: blamListSource">
  </ul>
  <p id="no-contactlist-span" hidden="hidden" class="no-items-msg">
    <b>No blam.</b>
  </p>
</div>

<!-- Blam ListView Template -->
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="blamListTemplate">
  <div>
    <div>
      <img id="blamPhoto" src="#: data.photoUri #"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="name">#: data.name #</div>
      <div>#: data.title #</div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <a data-role="button" class="callimg"
             data-phone="#: data.phone #" href="tel:#: data.phone #"
             data-rel="external"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a data-role="button" class="emailimg"
             href="mailto:#: data.email #"
             data-rel="external"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be fairly easy.

Add data-reload="true" to the view.

**Old - does not refresh**

```
<div data-role="view" data-title="Blam List" data-layout="main"
 data-model="APP" data-zoom="true">
```

**New - refreshes**

```
<div data-role="view" data-title="Blam List" data-layout="main"
 data-model="APP" data-zoom="true" data-reload="true">
```

**Edit** I accidentally put "data-refresh", which is wrong.  The correct value (edited to be correct) is "data-reload".